# Load profile data with xcode 6 app

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

Good afternoon,

I'm developing my first App using xcode 6 and now that I have created the interface for the Profile I need to load some data from the MySQL database. I have some "followers" and "pictures" that they are numbers and also I have to load the profile picture and load it in a UIImageView.

How can I do that using xcode?

Thanks in advance.

I know some PHP and MySQL, but I need some help with the xcode part.

Answer (score 0):

you need to expose a service that your iOS or Mac application can consume first, this is very important since is not a good idea to have a direct connection to MySQL.

After you have the service layer ready, exposing a standard response (json, xml, html.. ) You can consume the service using a Networking class.

If you want to cache, or your application need to consider offline scenarios, then you need to take into consideration core data or sqlite to persist the data.

I would recommend you to read more about iOS and Mac development before moving forward with an application.

Good luck!